# How to have a variable in more than two row-column in matrices?

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I have a `matrix` say `3 by 3`, in it I have a variable say G, which is `2 by 2`. But I don't know how to have such a matrix variable inside another one without splitting G?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question is unclear.

Comment: I want a variable to feel more than one cell in a matrix, like the second example in answer by @MickG

Comment: I would have been nice to know this in advance ;-) Please clearify your next posts!

Comment: @christian hupfer, thank you for recommendation,  but actually I think my question is clear. I wanted a "variable", but your answer is a constant.

Comment: Arguable but I keep my solution anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution uses the `multirow` and `multicol` packages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,multirow,multicol}

\begin{document}
\[\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$}} & 0 \\
 & & 0 \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0
\end{array}} & 1
\end{array}\right)
\quad
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\Huge$G$}} & 0 \\
 & & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

For more info about the arguments passed to `\multicolumn` and `\multirow`, read the documentation of the relevant packages. To adjust the alignment, one can use `\raisebox` (vertical) or add space (horizontal). The second multicolumn in the first example is to correctly align the 0 on the bottom-left corner, which would otherwise be too far to the left -- try and see!

Comment: As I suspected :). You're welcome. As you will know, there are other font size macros (`\large`, `\LARGE`, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Matrix in matrix can be nested and using the `bracket` - less `matrix` environment to keep the columns or rows aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix} 
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} & \begin{matrix} 2   \\ 1 \end{matrix} \\
\begin{matrix} 4 & 3 \end{matrix} & 5 \\
\end{pmatrix} 
\]
\end{document}
```

The spacing is however changed a little bit:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another way to show submatrices:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\left( \begin{array}{cc|c}
    1 & 0 & 2 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 \\
 \hline
    4 & 3 & 5
\end{array} \right)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: submatrix]